# PHP - Deleting an entry from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$_SESSION['food'] = array( 

// ARRAY 1
array(
      "name" => "apple",
      "shape" => "round",
      "color" => "red"
  ),

// ARRAY 2
   array(
      "name" => "banana",
      "shape" => "long",
      "color" => "yellow"
  )
);
```

I want to search through all keys in all child arrays and delete the entire child array if the search term is found.

So, basically:

1. If searching for "long", the entire Array 2 is removed.
2. If searching for "apple", the entire Array 1 is removed.

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone. I couldn't get any of the examples to work, but in the end I sorted it out by assigning each child array an associative key, which made it simple for me to find out the sub-array I need to delete. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $child_value) {
        if ($child_value == $search_term) {
            unset($array[$key]);
            continue 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many dimensions you have, you can use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

I haven't tested the following, but it should work:

```
$unset = array_search('apple', $_SESSION['food']);
unset($_SESSION['food'][$unset]);
```

Comment: This would not work. Array_search only searches the first level of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<?php
function deleteObjWithProperty($search,$arr)
  {
  foreach ($arr as &$val)
    {
    if (array_search($search,$val)!==false)
      {
      unlink($val);
      }
    }
  return $arr;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['food'] = array( 

// ARRAY 1
array(
      "name" => "apple",
      "shape" => "round",
      "color" => "red"
 ),

// ARRAY 2
array(
     "name" => "banana",
     "shape" => "long",
     "color" => "yellow"
  )
);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($_SESSION['food']).'</pre>';

$arr_food = array();
$search_term = 'apple';

foreach($_SESSION['food'] AS $arr) {
   if($arr['name'] == $search_term) {
    unset($arr);
  }
$arr_food[] = $arr;
}

$_SESSION['food'] = $arr_food;
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_SESSION['food']).'</pre>';
```